# Any built-in function in pandas/python which converts a list like data into a list

Tags: python, list, pandas

Suppose I have a data like [1 2 3 4]
Any built-in function in pandas/python which converts into a list
like [1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: "like [1 2 3 4]" is not an adequate description of the existing representation of the data.

Comment: from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
rfe = RFE(gbr, 15)
rfe = rfe.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print(rfe.support_)  if you know the sklearn, the ref.ranking_ returns a similar data structure:
[13  7  1  1  1  1  1 11  1  6  1  1  1  1 14  1  5 22 19 15 20 12 16  3  1
 17  1  1  4 10 21  1  9 18  2  8]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is the split function, however before calling it on your string, you must get rid of the [ and ], or else instead of `['1', '2', '3', '4']`, you will get `['[1', '2', '3', '4]']`, so instead of `s.split()`, we do `s[1:-1].split()`, also this means your list is strings instead of ints (`'1'` instead of `1`), but that is easily fixable:
`[int(i) for i in s[1:-1].split()]`

Comment: It works after convert [1 2 3 4]  as string '[1 2 3 4]' .Thank you so much. @Karan Elangovan